# Opening fb://messaging/{user_id} using {app_scoped_user_id}

Tags: android, facebook, messenger

I understand that it is not possible to get the public user id of a Facebook user by an App. But app scoped id's do not work with any  fb:\\ protocol. I can neither open someone's profile nor the chat in messenger using the app scoped id's. Is there any way I can do this?

My app needs people to connect to each other using messenger. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: did you find any solution?